# Java executor can't add a new task during execution

Tags: java, multithreading

Tried to use executor to run some tasks in parallel.  What's special about my assignment is that, one of the executor threads may add a new tasks during execution (shown in the following code snippet).

The following code snippet doesn't do what I need. Would appreciate if someone gives me some ideas.

```
 public void testThread2() throws Exception {
      Table obj = new Table();//only one object
      ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
      Random rand = new Random();
      final ArrayList<Integer> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
      tasks.add(1);
      tasks.add(2);
      tasks.add(3);
      tasks.add(4);
      for (Integer t: tasks) {
         taskExecutor.execute(() -> {
            for (int j = 0; j< 5; j++) {
               System.out.println(j * 100 + t);
               try {
                  Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(300));
               } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
            if (t == 2) {
               tasks.add(5);
            }
         });
      }
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      taskExecutor.shutdown();
   }
```

Comment: By the time taks 2 runs, the `for` loop is probably finished or (if the loop takes more than 300ms to run) the `for` loop will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, you are right.  In my case, I can make the main thread wait longer. My headache is, not being able to add a task to executor threads to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the code that should run in an extra method and replace the `tasks.add(5);` with a call to `taskExecutor.execute()`.

```
 public void testThread2() throws Exception {
    Table obj = new Table();//only one object
    ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    Random rand = new Random();
    final ArrayList<Integer> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    tasks.add(1);
    tasks.add(2);
    tasks.add(3);
    tasks.add(4);
    for (Integer t: tasks) {
        taskExecutor.execute(() -> testThread2Runner(t, taskExecutor));
    }
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    taskExecutor.shutdown();
}

public static void testThread2Runner(int t, ExecutorService taskExecutor) {
    for (int j = 0; j< 5; j++) {
        System.out.println(j * 100 + t);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(300));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (t == 2) {
        taskExecutor.execute(() -> testThread2Runner(5, taskExecutor));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @JohannesKuhn!

Comment: You should consider using a `ForkJoinPool` - they often have better performance when you add new Tasks within tasks (called `fork()`).